# How can I sum these two arrays into a new one?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I sum these two arrays into a new one? Where the first value of the `arrayA` sums the first value of the `arrayB`?

```java
public class Exercises {

    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int numbersA[] = new int[5];
        int numbersB[] = new int[5];
        int numbersC[] = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            out.print("Please insert a number for the first array: ");
            numbersA[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            out.print("Please insert a number for the second array: ");
            numbersB[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numbersC[j] = (numbersA.length[i] + numbersB.length[i]);
        }
        {

            out.print("The sum of the two arrays are: " + numbersC[j] + " ");
        }
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: give an example of arrayA, arrayB, arrayC. Your question is not clear. You want sum(arrayA elements) in arrayB[0] place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close. `numbersA[i]` and `numbersB[i]` (not the `length` of each array). Also, you don't need `j` and should print the prelude before the loop. Like,

```
out.print("The sum of the two arrays are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] + numbersB[i];
    out.print(numbersC[i] + " ");
}
out.println();
```

Finally, your code relies on magic numbers (hard coded array lengths). That is bad practice, instead you should use the `array.length` so your code doesn't require changing when your array sizes change. Like,

```
int[] numbersA = new int[5];
int[] numbersB = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < numbersA.length; i++) {
    out.print("Please insert a number for the first array: ");
    numbersA[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbersB.length; i++) {
    out.print("Please insert a number for the second array: ");
    numbersB[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
}
int[] numbersC = new int[Math.min(numbersA.length, numbersB.length)];
out.print("The sum of the two arrays are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < numbersC.length; i++) {
    numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] + numbersB[i];
    out.print(numbersC[i] + " ");
}
out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now my code works. I just have a question "int[] numbersC = new int[Math.min(numbersA.length, numbersB.length)];" what is the purpose of this? Because I found out the code can works with or without it

Comment: @John If `numbersA` and `numbersB` aren't the same length, take the length of the shorter one; without that, if the lengths differ your code will throw an exception and terminate.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the `numbersC[j] = (numbersA.length[i] + numbersB.length[i]);`

length from both
use this shape
    numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] + numbersB[i];
i think it will be work now